# What is deployment in SSIS? Do I must deploy project/package for business use?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis

There are many answers about 'how' to deploy a project or package. But I can't find any answers about 'why' do I have to deploy my project/package.

Can't I use them without deployment? What is the differences between deployed and non-deployed? Is it advised to use deployed projects/packages for business purposes? Then why?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you. If you deploy the SSIS, you can take advantage of executing the SSIS through a schedule batch job, whereas if you don't deploy, you have to run it manually every time.